# Having trouble accessing a table with my SQL query. Not getting the desired result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble displaying setid's from the table 'sets' with my SQL query. I'm only receiving setid's from 'inventory', not from 'sets'.

```
$setidquery = "SELECT inventory.itemid,
                        inventory.setid,
                        inventory.colorid,
                        inventory.itemtypeid,
                        colors.colorname,
                        parts.partname,
                        parts.partid,
                        sets.setid
                        FROM inventory
                        JOIN parts ON inventory.itemid = parts.partid
                        JOIN colors ON inventory.colorid = colors.colorid
                        JOIN sets ON sets.SetID = inventory.SetID
                        WHERE sets.setid = '$_COOKIE[setid]'
                        ORDER BY partname ASC
                        LIMIT 1000";
```

'$_COOKIE[setid]' is a search from a previous stage, so as you can probably guess, that will be the specific 'SetID'. But when enter a setid from the table sets, nothing shows up.

For example the set 375-2 shows up fine, because that set is in the table inventory, but the set 0011-2 does not show up, because that one is in the table sets.

Database scheme: http://weber.itn.liu.se/~stegu76/TNMK30-2016/legodatabasen.pdf

**Goal: To print a table with sets from both inventory and sets.**

Sorry for repeating myself a lot, just trying to be specific.

Comment: So you want any result that that exists in _either_ `inventory` _or_ `sets`?

Comment: Yes i want to print a table with sets from both sets and inventory

Comment: @RiggsFolly He joins on `sets` with `sets.SetID = inventory.SetID`, so adding it in the `WHERE` clause again is not necessary

Comment: So we know that something can exist in `sets` but not `inventory`. Is it possible for something to exist in `inventory` but not in `sets`?

Comment: "For example the set 375-2 shows up fine, because that set is in the table inventory, but the set 0011-2 does not show up, because that one is in the table sets." The JOIN clause means that it will only select those rows where the row's value for `SetID` in `inventory` matches a `setID` in sets. That is the whole point of an inner join. So if you have no rows in inventory where the `setID` equals "0011-2", then you won't see that value in your results.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your expected result is. If you're just trying to list inventory items, then you don't need a JOIN to sets at all, unless you need to merge in a field from there (e.g. Setname) and display it with the inventory item, to make it clearer to the reader (instead of just showing a meaningless ID). In that case you'd just have your WHERE clause match on inventory.SetID instead.

Comment: @ADyson But can i not do a FULL JOIN?

Comment: yes you could, but why? What does it tell you? You'll just get a list of inventory items, with each inventory item listed multiple times - once for every row in sets. Plus you'll get any records from sets which don't have a match in inventory, and vice versa. e.g. see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp. Not sure how useful that is to anyone?

Comment: Try setting up your tables at http://sqlfiddle.com/, define the expected result and refer to your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JOIN it only get's the records where sets.SetID = inventory.SetID match. If you only have a record in the table sets and not in inventory the records don't match with your join. You probably need to use RIGHT JOIN to also show records that don't have matching results with the Inventory table.